# How are redirects to a special page explaining page moves a security Hole

Tags: security, redirection

I've been hearing at work that once we move our web platform, that unhanded redirects that could go to a spcial page telling the user where their requested page has moved to would present a security issue. These users are corporate intranet authenticated users and I am missing the security issue. What could it be? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the _rumor mill_ is a good place to get security information. Whoever you got this from should be able to _clearly_ explain the security issue; if not, they are either misinformed or blowing smoke.